# C Programm should start if the char input is correct

Tags: c

I'm new in coding and I have an assignment which should run further if the char input is correct and there are four opinion for the input: <Y,y,N,n>.
If the input is one of these four the program should go on.
I've tried it with that, but the problem is that I always have type in all four char before the program goes on.
Has anyone a solution?

```
compare_j = strcmp(str_1, input)
compare_N = strcmp(str_3, input)
...
...

 while (compare_j != 0|| compare_N != 0 || compare_j != 0 || compare_J != 0)
    {
      printf("wrong input!\n");
      scanf("%s", &input[0]);
    }
```

Comment: You aren't changing the value of any of the `compare_*` variables inside the loop

Comment: You're also checking the result of `compare_j` twice, and presumably never checking for the lower-case 'n'.

Answer (score 1):

Your program may have several other bugs, but you could try this:

```
while (compare_j != 0 && compare_N != 0 && compare_j != 0 && compare_J != 0)
```

Comment: Also like the comments suggested, you should probably re-calculate the strcmp(...) inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Try using a do-while loop, and move the input, compare stuff inside. Also your exit condition is wrong. You are checking if all those `char`s match at the same time, which is impossible.

You are checking `compare_j` twice instead of `compare_n`!

```
int compare_j;
int compare_J;
int compare_n;
int compare_N;

do {
    // Read input
    scanf("%s", &input[0]);

    // Compare
    compare_j = strcmp(str_1, input);
    compare_N = strcmp(str_3, input);
    ..
    ..

}while(compare_n == 0 || compare_N == 0 || compare_j == 0 || compare_J == 0);
```

This way you are checking that any of those chars match, and exit if not. Also moving the input/compare functions inside the loop, you don't need to write it twice.

Comment: do...while is indeed better but your while() condition is wrong